# R - grouping a text vector with counts

Tags: r, group-by

This should be very simple, but I cannot find out how to do it.

Suppose I have the vector:
('cat', 'hat', 'hat', 'mouse').

I would like to group by each word in the vector and calculate the number of times the word occured. The output should be

'cat':1

'hat':2

'mouse':1

How do you do this in R?

Answer (score 0):

With [table](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/table)

```r
table( c('cat', 'hat', 'hat', 'mouse') )
```